# how to retain the dropdown values when we click on back button

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a first page with 4 dropdowns. when i select the first dropdown there is a Ajax call will filter the other 3 dropdowns data, and click on submit button to display the second page.Now when i click on back button the dropdowns in the first page has to retain the data. only first dropdown is retaining the data, other 3 dropdowns having the initial data(not filtered data). So i am making a Ajax call on load function to see if the first dropdown is selected then i am filtering the other 3 dropdowns. The problem here is how to set the dropdown box selected value default. I have used like this: `$('#hospital').val(varHospital);`
But its not setting it. How do u set the dropdown to select a some value by default in JQUERY in java

Comment: **Java** is not **ECMAScript** (AKA: Javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#hospital').val(varHospital);
```

is correct. You have to make sure that `varHospital` contains value and not text of the `<option>` tag i.e.

```
<option value="varHospital">Text</option>
```

When you call the above jQuery line, the Option with `varHospital` will be selected. If `varHospital` is not present in the select list, there will be no change.